# Python : Replace statement in list with abbreviation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have three lists in the given format:

```
A = ['**New fund offering** documents required for opening an account in the name of a single Individual', 'Can an Individual open more than one Investment Account or folio']
B = [u'**New fund offering**', u'NFOs', u'Systematic investment plan', u'Systematic investment plans', u'SIPs', u'SWPs']
C = [u'**NFO',** u'NFO', u'SIP', u'SIP', u'SIP', u'SWP']
```

The aim is to replace the phrase found in list **A** with corresponding abbreviation in list **C**, if the phrase matches in list **B**. Please let me know how to do this in Python. So the final list **A** will become :

```
A = ['NFO documents required for opening an account in the name of a single Individual', 'Can an Individual open more than one Investment Account or folio']
```

Comment: any attemp that you could show us?

Comment: use ``dict(zip(B,C))`` to create a mapping. Then consider how to do your replacments. Problems may be, greedy vs. non-greedy matches, replacments which may depend on the order they are used (i.e. replacment A creates a string, which can be replaced with B, which would not have been possible without A), etc.

Comment: That said, you simply need the **replace** method ... which you *should* have found when you searched the Python documentation for string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` to replace parts of the string and it's possible to use `in` to check for matches:

```
for idx_a, substring in enumerate(A):
    for part, replacement in zip(B, C):
        if part in substring:
            A[idx_a] = A[idx_a].replace(part, replacement)
```